# How to change increment value in a scala generator?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I'm trying to create a number that's inside of a range with scalacheck generators like:

```
Gen.chooseNum(min, max)
```

But it defaults to the increment value of `1` but I wanted it to increment with `0.5`.
What is the solution for this?

Comment: What is the type for `min` and `max`?

Comment: They are Ints. Min was 5 and Max was 15. This choses values like 10, 11, but I need to also have 10.5, 11.5, etc.

Comment: Well there's your 1st problem: `Int` in produces `Int` out, but `10.5`, `11.5`, etc., aren't `Int` values. You'll want to use type `Float` or type `Double` instead. Your 2nd problem is that `Gen` probably won't focus on the `x.5` values without some prodding. Use the `specials` parameter for that.

Comment: It doesn't focus on the increment value at all. Even if they were doubles, how can I change the increment? Or if the value is 2 and not 0.5? I can't see a straightforward aproach

Comment: Where does your expectation of an "increment" come from? I don't find it in any of the documentation that I've found so far. From [this page](https://www.scalacheck.org/files/scalacheck_2.11-1.14.0-api/#org.scalacheck.Gen$) it says of `chooseNum()`: _"Generates numbers within the given inclusive range, with extra weight on zero, +/- unity, both extremities, and any special numbers provided."_ So, as I mentioned before, if you want "extra weight" on, say, `10.5` and `11.5`, for example, then you should include those values in the `specials` parameter.

Comment: If I put a range of, let's say, 15 and 20, it'll generate 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, and 20, but I need it to generate 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, etc. If I do it with doubles, I'll have, for example, 15.234 or something. So min, min + 0.5 until max - 0.5 and max. I do understand what you're saying, but the problem that I have is that I need those .5 values in the given range and I was trying to see if there's a straightforward solution to this without the need of another function

Comment: It really looks like `Gen.chooseNum()` is the wrong tool for the job but, without seeing how you're using it in the larger code context, it's difficult to suggest an alternative. BTW, I think that increment-by-1 sequence you see with `Int` input is probably an artifact of the limited range between `min` and `max`. I doubt things would be so orderly for a much larger range.

Comment: I would just write a new function reusing `Gen.chooseNum` for it, like `Gen.chooseNum(a, b) * 0.5`

Answer (score 0):

You can generate integers that are multiples of 5 and then divide them by 10.

```scala
Gen.choose(min * 10, max * 10)
  .map(_ / 5 * 5)
  .map(_.toDouble / 10)
```